# Creating a Conditional Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a column that is only mandatory if the value for another column is "Y" (if it is "N", then it is not mandatory). The type of the other column is a CHAR with length 1. How could I do this using a Trigger? I believe a trigger is more appropriate than a check would be, but please let me know what you think.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `CHECK` constraint to the table. For example:

```
create table t (
  active char(1),
  amount number(6),
  constraint c1 check (active <> 'Y' or amount is not null)
);
```

Then you can try to insert:

```
insert into t (active, amount) values ('N', null); -- OK

insert into t (active, amount) values ('N', 123); -- OK

insert into t (active, amount) values ('Y', 123); -- OK

insert into t (active, amount) values ('Y', null); -- fails!
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f7d49908c6e0f5ef813b9e2963e6d84).

Comment: wouldnt a trigger constraint be more appropriate

Comment: @JasmineDogu A trigger would also work. I tend to use contraints since they are far simpler. A trigger has much more properties and features (transaction participation, execution opportunity, much more coding and debugging, etc.). But it's definitively an option.